# Spring, how to encode and decode a String

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to encode a `String` so I can store it safely in my database. Most password encoders, like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), can only hash your `String`, with no way of getting it back (which for a password makes sense), and I want to decode it when I retrieve the information from my database.

I tried using `org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors.queryableText()` but the method is deprecated.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: you may have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-aes-encryption-decryption

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the string that you're trying to store?  Is it a password, credit card number, some other form of personal identifiable information (PII)?  There are decent solutions for all these that don't include encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 4):

```java
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class CryptoManager {
    //Key for encryption and decryption
    public static final byte[] KEY =
            {118, 106, 107, 122, 76, 99, 69, 83, 101, 103, 82, 101, 116, 75, 101, 127};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String salt = "HELLO";
        String encryptedString = encrypt(salt, "HelloWorld12345");
        System.out.println("Encripted string is " + encryptedString);

        String decryptedString = decrypt(salt, encryptedString);
        System.out.println("Decrypted string is " + decryptedString);

    }

    public static String encrypt(String salt, String plainText) {
        if (plainText == null || plainText.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data to encrypt!");
            return plainText;
        }
        Cipher cipher = null;
        String encryptedString = "";
        try {
            // Creating a Cipher object
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

            // Creating a secret key from KEY byte array
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");

            // Initializing a Cipher object
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            // Encrypting the plain text string
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(salt.concat(plainText).getBytes());

            // Encoding the encrypted text to Base64
            encryptedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught while encrypting : " + ex);
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }


    public static String decrypt(String salt, String cipherText) {
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data to decrypt!");
            return cipherText;
        }
        String decryptedString = "";
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            // Creating a Cipher object
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");

            // Creating a secret key from KEY byte array
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");

            // Initializing a Cipher object
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            // Decoding from Base64
            byte[] encryptedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText.getBytes());

            // Decrypting to plain text
            decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedText));

        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught while decrypting : " + ex);
        }
        return decryptedString.replace(salt, "");
    }

}
```

[Check this out for more detail](https://www.tutorialsbuddy.com/encryption-and-decryption-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store the data securely in database, what you really need to do is encrypt the data before writing to database from application.

To encrypt/decrypt the data from application you can use Symmetric key algorithm like [AES](https://www.baeldung.com/java-aes-encryption-decryption).

To automatically convert this in entity you can add a converter in corresponding column

```
@Convert(converter = DataEncryptDecryptConverter.class)
@Column(name = "DATA")
private String data;
```

And the converter

```
@Converter
@Component
public class DataEncryptDecryptConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
      // Code to encrypt data
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
     // Code to decrypt data
    }
```

}